# How to handle the initial value of a dojo.Stateful widget?

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo

I'm using dijit.form.Select widget. Since all dojo widgets base off of dojo.Stateful it is possible to watch for property changes. I'm tracking `value` property of Select widget and all works fine. For example:

```
this.select.watch("value", lang.hitch(this, function (attr, oldVal, newVal) {
...
```

But this approach works when `value` property of widget is changed. But how can I call the same function (second parameter of `watch` method) for the initial value of the widget (when oldVal is undefined)? By default `watch` doesn't fired in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your watch function will not fire upon loading your widget. However, if you need to call your function with the Select's initial value, you can simply define your function beforehand and then use it in both places like this:

```
var myFunction = function(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
  // Do something useful
}

var initVal = this.select.get("value");
myFunction(null, null, initVal); 

this.select.watch("value", lang.hitch(this, myFunction));
```

Alternatively, you can have a custom widget extend from `dijit/form/Select` and override its `_setValueAttr` function. This will be called with the initial value by the time your Select widget starts up.

```
var CustomSelect = declare(Select, {
  _setValueAttr: function(val) {
     this.inherited(arguments);  // Allow dojo to handle the complex Select widget logic
     // Do custom stuff with val...
  }
});
```